# JQuery: Make hovered <li> move

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of lists on my webpage and I'm trying to use JQuery to have these list items move to the side a bit when hovered over. This is what I have so far and it doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div>Text1</li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div>Text2</li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div>Text3</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").hover(function() {
        $("div").animate({
            width: '+=10px'
        });
    }, function() {
        $("div").animate({
            width: '-=10px'
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
      width : 0px;
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjpcr9ov/

Comment: Remove the ')' after function  =>  function)() {$("div").animate({

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code  and also get the [div inside the `li` by passing it's context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").hover(function() {
    $("div", this)
      .stop() // use stop for strop the previous animation
      .animate({
        width: '+=10px'
      });
  }, function() {
    //        -^----- remove `)` from here
    $("div", this)
      .stop() // use stop for strop the previous animation
      .animate({
        width: '-=10px'
      });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>Text1</li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>Text2</li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>Text3</li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE :**  Demo with nested span inside

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li span").hover(function() {
    $(this)
      .prev()
      // or
      // .parent() // get parent li
      // .find("div") // find div inside    
      .stop() // use stop for strop the previous animation
      .animate({
        width: '+=10px'
      });
  }, function() {
    $(this)
      .prev()
      // or
      // .parent() // get parent li
      // .find("div") // find div inside    
      .stop() // use stop for strop the previous animation
      .animate({
        width: '-=10px'
      });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Text1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Text2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Text3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works. Is it possible to limit the check for hover so that it only triggers when the mouse is over the text? Would this just be a matter of maybe putting <span> tags around the text and then checking for the hover on the span instead of the li?

Comment: @OlieAyre : check the additional snippet